# PHP: Enviar correo electrónico haciendo uso de la función mail() desde local

Tags: php, mail

Estoy intentando desarrollar un sistema de recuperación de contraseñas para los usuarios de mi página web a partir de este ejemplo:

https://www.instintoprogramador.com.mx/2019/12/sistema-de-restablecimiento-de.html

Específicamente, el trozo de código con el que se envía el correo es el siguiente:

```
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    // store token in the password-reset database table against the user's email
    $sql = "INSERT INTO password_reset(email, token) VALUES ('$email', '$token')";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    // Send email to user with the token in a link they can click on
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Reset your password on examplesite.com";
    $msg = "Hi there, click on this <a href=\"new_password.php?token=" . $token . "\">link</a> to reset your password on our site";
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    $headers = "From: info@examplesite.com";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    header('location: pending.php?email=' . $email);
  }
}
```

Yo he probado a hacer lo siguiente, una vez mi sistema comprueba que el correo corresponde a un usuario de mi base de datos:

```
    $toquen = bin2hex(random_bytes(50));

    $destinatario = $this->obtener("correo");
    $asunto = "50 años de Era Pop: Restauración de tu contraseña";
    $enlace = '<a href="lo_que_sea.php?token='.$toquen.'">aquí</a>';
    $cuerpo = "Hola, ".$nombre_usuario.", parece que has solicitado restaurar tu contraseña de acceso a 50 años de Era Pop; si es así, haz clic ".$enlace.". Si no has sido tú, simplemente ignora este correo.";
    $cuerpo_ajustado = wordwrap($cuerpo, 70);
    $encabezados = "From: 50erapop@gmail.com";
                
    mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo_ajustado, $encabezados);
```

Como las pruebas las hago desde mi local, he seguido este consejo, referenciado en el ejemplo inicial:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost/23061280#23061280

**EDICIÓN**: Yo estoy usando Wamp64.

He instalado Test Mail Server Tool:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y he configurado `php.ini` de la siguiente manera:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
smtp = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from ="50erapop@gmail.com"

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
; sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
; mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
; mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
; mail.log = syslog
```

Sin embargo, al intentar enviar el correo obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
( ! ) Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

¿Se os ocurre qué falta por configurar?

Comment: Parece que la herramienta que instalaste no se ha actualizado desde hace algún tiempo; de hecho, la guía de instalación es para Windows XP y el videotutorial para Windows 7. Lo único que se me ocurre es que no es compatible con tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Una opción más actualizada puede ser https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP

Comment: Estas utilizando XAMPP, WAMP o MAMP?   o  LINUX si mas?

Comment: Wamp64, Wilfredo. Ya he modificado el mensaje inicial para reseñarlo.

Comment: Sugiero usar [phpmailer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer) para estos propósitos. Es más fácil de configurar y trabaja en cualquier plataforma.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando Xammp debes activar el servicio `Mercury` que es por donde salen los Mails,  presiona el botón `admin`

Reenvía el correo nueva mente y comenta si te muestra el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra opcion es configurar un servidor SMTP.

Comment: No, estoy usando Wamp64. Se me olvidó reseñarlo.